# Not able to read Impala view correctly using Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, impala

I am trying to read an Impala view from Spark Scala program using SparkSQL API.

My code is like this

```
val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder().appName("HiveLoader").master(new Sparkconf().get("spark.master", local[*]).getorCreate() 

sparkSession.conf.set("spark.sql.crossJoin.enabled", true) 

val df = sparkSession.sql("Select * from view1")
```

where `view1` is the view in Impala which is created by joining two or more Impala tables. The above code is not reading the complete view and it's not giving the correct result. For example, the count of this view in Impala is 410234 but it's reading only 371 records.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `df.explain()`?